# How to go from ~p and (p → False) ∧ (q → False) → False) to (q -> False) -> False in Coq

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I'm very new to propositional logic and coq. Can anyone help me prove ~p->((p → False) ∧ (q → False) → False) |- q in Coq? I intuitively understand this must be true as if you have ~p, (p → False) ∧ (q → False) → False is only true if (q -> False) -> False, so Q must be true. I attached an image of the statement on coq.

Edit: I've really spent a long time trying and can't figure out how to show (q -> False) -> False from ~p. Sorry if this is trivial

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, your assumption that this will be easy to proof is not quite right: it turns out that this claim is equivalent to Excluded Middle!

Let's take this a bit more slowly: The "excluded middle" principle holds in classical logic, but not in the intuitionistic base logic that Coq uses. It states that for any proposition $P$, the formula $P \vee \neg P$ is true. For various reasons (not least since Coq implements a constructive logic, and excluded middle is non-constructive), by default, this principle does *not* hold in Coq.

Now, to prove your goal, it would be relatively easy to show that you can derive $(q \to \bot) \to \bot$, where $\bot$ stands for false - but deriving $q$ from that is known to require Excluded Middle (or, more precisely, it would be enough that $q$ is decidable, i.e., you have a proof that $q \vee \neg q$ holds - in that case, do a case analysis on this proof. If you get $q$, you're done by assumption; if you get $\neg q$, you have a contradiction. Coq's `assumption` and `contradiction` tactics will handle these cases for you, as will the `easy` tactic).

Conversely, it is well-known that if you have $\neg \neg p \to p$ for all $p$, you can prove excluded middle (IIRC, this is even an exercise in Pierce's Software Foundations). So there is no hope to prove this without additional information.

If you want to assume excluded middle, the easiest way is to load the `Classical` library - put a `Require Import Classical_Prop.` at the top of your development. You can then use the lemmas given here: https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.Logic.Classical_Prop.html.
Alternatively, you can assume excluded middle yourself, either as an assumption to your lemma, or using the `Axiom` command (see the file linked above for how to do this).

*Edit*: How to derive $(q \to \bot) \to \bot$.

The easiest way for a beginner to do this is to use forward reasoning, like this:

```
# State that we will now prove a sub-goal with the given type
assert ((q -> False) -> False).
intros Hcontra.
# We now have three hypotheses, H and H0 as above, and Hcontra: q -> False
# Note that our goal is now "False"!
apply H.
split; assumption.
```

Alternatively, if you don't mind using automation, you can also prove this via the `tauto` tactic.

Comment: I understand that deriving q from (q→⊥)→⊥ requires the use of The Law of the Excluded Middle. What I don't really know is how to derive (q→⊥)→⊥ in coq. I can logically deduce this to be true, but I don't know how to implement it in code.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone help me prove $\def\False{\operatorname{\sf False}}\lnot p\to((p\to\False)\land((q\to\False)\to\False))\vdash q$

No, because this sequent is invalid.   When we value $p$ as true and $q$ as false, we value the premise as true and the consequent as false.

Comment: Some errant parentheses got into the mix here... the sequent in the post is classically (but not intuitionistically) valid.